# PHP fopen() Error: failed to open stream

Tags: php, linux, fopen, permission-denied

I am getting this error when my php script tries to access text file.

`PHP Warning:  fopen(UPfileName.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /path/to/script.php`

Here are the permissions of my directory and file:

`abc/www/file.txt`

`drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  abc/`

`drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root   www/`

`-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  root file.txt`

Please tell what should I do to get ride of this error.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: I feel you should try full file system path in your `fopen()`.

Comment: You need to give full permission for the folder abc.
You run this command sudo chmod -R 777 abc

Comment: Please show your current code!!!

Comment: @RamSharma its still not working. What else I am missing?

Comment: @SinsilMathew : I can't give 777 permissions on the acb/ directory.